# resizing textAreaInput in column layout

Tags: r, shiny

I can't manage to resize the textAreaInput in the following layout:

[image]

I've tried `width = 100%` and also `col=200` or more, but somehow the left field is always narrow. Removing `fluidPage` seems to help, but then the two columns are stacked on top of each other (not sure why).

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  #UI
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(
    column(8,
           textAreaInput("text1", 'input', value = paste(sample(letters, 100, T), collapse = ""), 
                         cols=80, rows = 5, resize = "vertical")),
    column(4, 
           verbatimTextOutput("text2"))

  )),
  #Server
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$text2 <- renderText({ 
      paste(sample(letters, 100, T), collapse = "")
    })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  #UI
  ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(
    column(8,
           textAreaInput("text1", 'input', width=600, value = paste(sample(letters, 100, T), collapse = ""), 
                         cols=80, rows = 5, resize = "vertical")),
    column(4, 
           verbatimTextOutput("text2"))

  )),
  #Server
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$text2 <- renderText({ 
      paste(sample(letters, 100, T), collapse = "")
    })

  }
)
```

You  need to set up the argument `width = ...` using px and not %, in this case i have used `width=600`

[image]